# MPMoviePlayerViewController setFullScreen: shows a white screen

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I wanted to set the mp4 video to full screen and it seems straight forward but whenever I call the setFullscreen method, it becomes a white blank screen. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
......
moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];
[self presentModalViewController:moviePlayerViewController animated:YES];

moviePlayerController = [moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer];
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];

[[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] play]; 
[[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
```

If I comment out the last line, the video will play but somehow the full screen becomes a white screen instead of just maximizing the video.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you call `setFullscreen` before `prepareToPlay`?

Comment: Same thing happened. I also tried using the moviePlayerController and they both yield same results...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and this code worked for me.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

            [moviePlayer.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [moviePlayer.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
            [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
            [moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```